# cassandra 2.2.8: sstableverify - GC overhead limit exceeded

Tags: java, memory-leaks, cassandra, cassandra-cli

I suspect I've corrupted my sstables for a table therefore I'm running `sstableverify` utility while node is down. I'm receiving messages like `[GC overhead limit exceeded]`

Seeking help if this issue can be worked-around or addressed.. thanks in advance!

> sstableverify -v enterprise ale_state_access_point
>
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead
>   limit exceeded
>           at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3332)
>           at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.ensureCapacityInternal(AbstractStringBuilder.java:124)
>           at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:649)
>           at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:202)
>           at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.Descriptor.filenameFor(Descriptor.java:170)
>           at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.Descriptor.filenameFor(Descriptor.java:125)
>           at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.format.SSTableReader.load(SSTableReader.java:709)
>           at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.format.SSTableReader.load(SSTableReader.java:672)
>           at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.format.SSTableReader.open(SSTableReader.java:466)
>           at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.format.SSTableReader.openNoValidation(SSTableReader.java:377)
>           at org.apache.cassandra.tools.StandaloneVerifier.main(StandaloneVerifier.java:89)
>   ERROR 20:33:15 LEAK DETECTED: a reference
>   (org.apache.cassandra.utils.concurrent.Ref$State@6d42f926) to class
>   org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.format.SSTableReader$InstanceTidier@1047072254:/cassandra/data/enterprise/ale_state_access_point-ae4c50d0d67a11e696b25735df805631/lb-79600-big
>   was not released before the reference was garbage collected ERROR
>   20:33:15 LEAK DETECTED: a reference
>   (org.apache.cassandra.utils.concurrent.Ref$State@69f4a15d) to class
>   org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.format.SSTableReader$InstanceTidier@1968390106:/cassandra/data/enterprise/ale_state_access_point-ae4c50d0d67a11e696b25735df805631/lb-58267-big
>   was not released before the reference was garbage collected

Answer (score 1):

I would guess you have a lot of sstables given its failing just building the descriptors. If you have the memory on the system try increasing heap (default 256mb):

`MAX_HEAP_SIZE=4G sstableverify -v enterprise ale_state_access_point`

Comment: Thanks @Chris Lohfink, you're right on.. there were a lot of sstables so what i did is to kick in compaction with changing compaction strategy of few CFs.. that addressed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

There is only so much you can do if you tampered with the sstables and broke them. This would also happen when the node would try to load the table. I would suggest restoring from backup or scrubbing the table.

Comment: Hi Marko.. thank you again for you reply. I'm indeed trying to scrub table though both sstablescrub & sstableverify utilities throws OOM message. nodetool scrub just hangs and never completes.. .therefore I'm looking for reasons why these utilities are going oom and if we can work around the issues.